How to filter out tag groups in org-mode?
I have created a grouptag for my team as follows-
(setq org-tag-alist '((:startgrouptag)
                        ("my_team")
                        (:grouptags)
                        ("A")
                        ("B")
                      (:endgrouptag))

Now, I have assigned some TODO tasks to my team members. Some tasks belong to A, some to B, and some to both A and B. I assign a tag related to A and/or B for each task. There are some other tags that are related to me. Now, I want to filter out the tasks of my_team from my agenda TODO list. How can I do so?
I followed this link to filter out tasks based on tags of A or B. However, this does not filter based on groupgtags (my_team for my case). How can I achieve this?

Here's two simple agenda custom commands that do what I thought you wanted (the j command) and what you really wanted (the k command):
("j" "my team"
       ((agenda "")
         (tags-todo "my_team"))
       )
;;
("k" "not my team"
       ((agenda "")
         (tags-todo "-my_team"))
       )

They're a simplification of the one from the linked question (which I don't think is as complicated as the question and the answers make it: instead of using skip functions and regexps, use tag inheritance - which is on by default, at least today - it might not have been a dozen years ago though).
Here's a test file:
#+TAGS: [ my_team :  A B ]

* Tasks

** TODO one                                                 :A:

** TODO two                                                 :B:

** TODO three                                               :A:B:

** TODO four                                                :my_team:

** TODO five

** TODO six                                                  :me:


* Code

#+begin_src elisp
  (add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
               '("j" "my team"
                 ((agenda "" )
                  (tags-todo "my_team"))
                 ))

  (add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands           
               '("k" "not my team"
                 ((agenda "")
                  (tags-todo "-my_team"))
                 ))

#+end_src

Run the source block with C-c C-c to add the commands to the agenda dispatcher, add the file to the agenda list with C-c [, run M-x org-agenda and select first the j command. Here's the output for that:
Week-agenda (W51):
Monday     16 December 2024 W51
Tuesday    17 December 2024
Wednesday  18 December 2024
Thursday   19 December 2024
Friday     20 December 2024
Saturday   21 December 2024
Sunday     22 December 2024

─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────Headlines with TAGS match: my_team
  foo8:       TODO one                                              :A:
  foo8:       TODO two                                              :B:
  foo8:       TODO three                                            :A:B:
  foo8:       TODO four                                        :my_team:


That shows you all the TODO items, tagged with either or both members of the my_team tag group, or tagged with the tag group itself.
Now run M-x org-agenda again and select the k command. Here's the output for that:
Week-agenda (W52):
Monday     23 December 2024 W52
Tuesday    24 December 2024
Wednesday  25 December 2024
Thursday   26 December 2024
Friday     27 December 2024
Saturday   28 December 2024
Sunday     29 December 2024

─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Headlines with TAGS match: -my_team
  foo8:       TODO five
  foo8:       TODO six                                              :me:


That gives all the TODO items not tagged with members of the my_team tag group. The only items on it are untagged items or items tagged with the tag me.
This is one instance of a general search mechanism which you can also invoke interactively from the agenda dispatcher using the m command. The search syntax is described in Matching tags and properties in the Org mode manual. There are also several more complicated examples in that section. One warning: you will have to reread the section several times and try several examples before you can get your head around it all.

Hi, I think I didn't explain the question clearly. In the custom agenda, I want only my tasks to be visible, not of A, not of B, nor of my_team. Although, I would create a separate agenda for my team, for which your command works.

Sorry, I misunderstood. What you want is the equivalent of the negation of (tags-todo "my_team")? Every task that is not tagged A or B or A:B or my_team?  IOW, in the above example, tasks five and six?

Yes, exactly. I want a negation of the output produced by your answer.

See the edited answer.

That solves my use case. I couldn't find that part of the documentation.

Please try the link again. There was a failure the first time I clicked on it, but it succeeded the second time: the Org mode site might have had a temporary problem.
